# Find and print all the rows whose sub-elements have similar values

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, numpy, data-cleaning

My data set has following fields:

```
User        Product          Time
 A            10            10-JAN
 B            14            10-JAN
 C            20            10-JAN
 A            12            10-JAN
 B            12            11-JAN
 A            10            12-JAN
 D            08            12-JAN
 A            13            12-JAN
 B            14            13-JAN
 C            20            13-JAN
 A            12            14-JAN
 C            21            14-JAN
 A            10            15-JAN
```

and so on

I want to pull out and display only those users having bought similar product before, with the time stamp of purchase. So something like this:

```
ProductBought      User     Time           count
    10              A        10-JAN          3
    10              A        12-JAN          3
    10              A        15-JAN          3
    12              A        10-JAN          2
    12              A        14-JAN          2
    14              B        10-JAN          2
    14              B        13-JAN          2
    20              C        10-JAN          2
    20              C        13-JAN          2
```

and so on.

I tried using the shift funtion like this

```
df.sort_values(by=['User','Time'],ascending=True)    
df[(df.User==df.User.shift())&(df.productBought==df.productBought.shift()]
```

but I am not getting all the results using this. For example, only consecutive results which have same product is being captured. In our case, since before user A bought 10 again, it bought 12, so its not capturing that.
Also, if there are two consecutive records of the same user having the same product, the latest one is being showed, as

> df==df.shift()

only shows the record which was encountered last, and not all the records which have the same product. 
Is there any way I can achieve what I have displayed above?

Comment: What about using groupby? You could call groupby([‘Time’,’User’,’Product’])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use duplicated to get rows that have duplicated product-user pair, i.e. the user has bought the product before.

```
df2 = df[df.duplicated(['Product', 'User'], keep=False)]
```

Then, you can do sort etc...

To find out how many times the products are bought, you can use

```
df2.groupby(['Product', 'User']).count()
```

Comment: can we also find out how many of the times the product was bought?

Comment: You can use groupby and count. Answer updated above.

Comment: Yea I figured that out.

Comment: Thank you Tim! This was useful